# How to route midi to mauto pitch to control notes in audio

Tags: midi, pitch, fl-studio

I want to add mauto pitch to an audio sample and then route midi information to mauto pitch for it to adjust the notes in the audio to, like in this video:

but with fl studio instead. Ive researched the topic yet i can't seem to find much info on it, thank you!

Comment: Welcome! This question hasn't gotten a lot of attention yet. Perhaps a little editing might help. Are you committed to the MAutoPitch plugin, or simply looking to use autotune in general? Are you having trouble installing the plugin? Looking for help on how to actually use it? Where have you looked in your research already and what have you found?

Comment: @AndyBonner I've really only found vids on generators when it comes to using in/out ports, but they seem to work a bit differently and are usually involving a physical instrument, while i want to use midi info in an fl studio rack to control the pitch of an audio track using m-auto pitch, which yes, I'm quite set on using! I had no trouble installing or using it though, the plugin itself that is, i just simply want to know what the instructions for using fl studio to route midi information to m-auto for pitch adjustment to the track according to those midi notes.